# Is it possible to get a question disassociated from your account?

Tags: support

There is a question that I don't wish to be associate with my account any longer

Comment: That’s a shame, it’s a good question, just unfortunately difficult to answer.

Comment: What about turning the post into a wiki? It won't totally get rid of your name (contacting the staff as Fabian said), but at least it makes it much less obvious who asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "contact us" link in the footer and ask SE to disassociate the post. This is something only SE employees can do, moderators can't disassociate posts.